# Problems with gnome-control-center after upgrading to Debian Jessie and Gnome 3.14.1

Tags: debian, controls, upgrade, gnome

I recently upgraded my Debian system to Jessie/stable (which also included an update to Gnome 3.14.1). Since then, when I run

```
gnome-control-center network
```

, I am getting the following errors:

```
(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed

(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:9451): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
```

Also, the network information (IP/DNS/...) presented in the control center window differ from the actual settings - which nonetheless are working!

Besides this, I get a similar output for

```
gnome-control-center sharing
```

:

```
(gnome-control-center:9875): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:9875): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(gnome-control-center:9875): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed

(gnome-control-center:9875): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:9875): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-control-center:9875): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-control-center:9875): sharing-cc-panel-WARNING **: couldn't list networks: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing was not provided by any .service files
```

Here, all sharing options are disabled. And I cannot enable them.

Any suggestions what might cause such behaviour?